# What does の apply to after a list of items with と?

Tags: grammar, syntax, particle-の, particle-と, ambiguity

I've looked around, but I couldn't find an answer for this question.  Here's the example phrase that I'm trying to translate that I pulled from a light novel:

> せりとレタスとキャベツの違い

I'm not sure whether it means. My guess is either:

> the difference of parsley, lettuce, and cabbage

or:

> parsley, lettuce, and cabbage's difference (difference modifies cabbage only)

Logically, it should be the second, but I seem to recall that it can mean the first if you reason out the literal translation.

Comment: How else would you say "The difference of parsley, lettuce, and cabbage" in Japanese?

Comment: Use the list as before, end with the wa particle, and a verb for difference between,  Right, I'll add that I pulled this from a light novel and that I'm trying to translate it properly.

Comment: Do you mean「せりとレタスとキャベツは違う」? It'd be a sentence "Parsley, lettuce, and cabbage are different." 「せりとレタスとキャベツの違い」is a noun phrase, not a sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently, [@naruto](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/5010/naruto) mentioned the phrase 頭が赤い魚を食べた猫, which can be understood [in many ways](http://togetter.com/li/567493). There is some ambiguity in how each word relates to each other.

Among other possibilities, it could mean

- [(頭が赤い)魚]を食べた猫 (red-headed fish)
- [(頭が赤い)+(魚を食べた)]猫 (red-headed cat)

The same applies here. Consider the following pattern:

> ＡとＢとＣのＤ

As far as logic and grammar is concerned, this can be interpreted as either one of these possibilities:

1. (ＡとＢとＣ)のＤ
2. (ＡとＢ)と(ＣのＤ)
3. Ａと[(ＢとＣ)のＤ]

Note that A, B, C, and D can be nouns or noun phrases. If the latter, it could get even more confusing, so I won't consider this case.

Usually context resolves the ambiguity and makes it obvious. For the example you gave, that would be possibility (3): the difference between certain kinds of vegetables.

To illustrate the point, let me give some examples for each possibility.

(`《》` markers added by me for clarity)

①:

- 《せりとレタスとキャベツ》の違い
- 《ブランデーと梅酒と柑橘【かんきつ】ジャム》の大人[珈琲]【コーヒー】
- garden COLORING BOOK 《小鳥と花と動物》のぬり絵
- 《君と彼女と彼女》の恋

②:

- 勇者と少女と《変化の指輪》
- 「使命」と「運命」と「人生の意味」
- 僕と君と《夜空の星》
- 星杯騎士団【グラールリッター】と七耀教会【しちようきょうかい】と《黒【くろ】の史書【ししょ】》
- コナンと平次【へいじ】と《恋の暗号》

③:

Note the first sentence.

- [ポスドク]【postdoctor(al)】問題と《アメリカと日本の違い》
- 下妻物語【しもつまものがたり】と《ウルルと森の物語》
- 竹取物語【たけとりものがたり】と《伊邪那岐命【いざなぎのみこと】の伊邪那美命【いざなみのみこと】の物語》
- 《伊邪那岐命【イザナギノミコト】と伊邪那美命【イザナミノミコト】の夫婦神》と《伊邪那岐命と伊邪那美命の争いを仲裁した菊理媛大神【ククリヒメノオオカミ】》が祀られている
- 和風レシピと《梅酒と梅干しの作り方》

I had a hard time coming up with examples for case ③, but it's definitely possible.

To summarize, only context and common sense can tell you what の applies to, it depends on what the nouns or noun phrases A, B, C, and D are.

Lastly, if you *really* wanted to leave no ambiguity, you could resort to a lengthy phrase that says it explicitly, such as せりとレタスとキャベツという3つの(野菜・植物)の違い.

Answer (score 1):

You usually say ＡとＢの違い to mean "the difference between A and B" and ＡとＢとＣの違い to mean "the difference among A, B and C", and I think it would be more natural to interpret せりとレタスとキャベツの違い as "the difference of parsley, lettuce, and cabbage" than "parsley, lettuce and the difference of cabbage".