# The correct parsing of 無類 In this sentence

Tags: translation, parsing

So I'm having a friendly debate with someone over the correct parsing of this sentence:

> 隆之介のような無類のライトレベルを操る才覚なく

Namely the way 無類 is affecting it.

I'm of the opinion that the correct way to parse this is:

> He doesn't have the quick wits to handle unmatched light levels like Ryunosuke can. (I.e. Ryunosuke's light levels are unmatched)

But my buddy thinks it would be more accurate to say:

> He doesn't have the quick wits to handle light levels in an unmatched way like Ryunosuke can. (I.e. Ryunosuke's handling of light levels is unmatched)

I felt confident in my version but I'm seriously second guessing myself now. If someone could break it down I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is [purely context-dependent](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/46822/5010). What's the previous context? "Ryunosuke has an exceptional talent?" Or are they talking about varying strengths of *light levels* and "Ryunosuke has a talent of handling even strong *light levels*?"

That said, I tend to think 無類の modifies 才覚 unless the context is clearly about the varying strength of *light levels*. That is, the phrase **probably** means "He doesn't have an unmatched talent of handling *light levels* like that of Ryunosuke".