# Dealing with の ambiguities

Tags: grammar, particle-の

A simple example:

> 日本語**の**勉強**の**時間

In theory, there could be several interpretations possible:

> [日本語**の**勉強**の**] 時間
>
> 日本語**の** [勉強**の**時間]
>
> [日本語**の**] [勉強**の**] [時間]

Are there any general rules on how to deal with this kind of ambiguity?

Comment: Your example is a bit weird, but in general the answer is **context**. This kind of ambiguity exists in English as much as it does in Japanese, but rarely is it not obvious what is meant from the context.

Comment: Possibly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46817/5010 (I can think of only one sane interpretation of this phrase...)

Comment: Thanks, @naruto, that really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

**(A's B)'s C**:

- 財布の中の500円玉
  a 500 yen coin in the wallet
- パパのパパのパパ
  dad's dad's dad
- 不思議の国のアリス
  Alice in Wonderland
- 日本語の勉強の時間
  time to study Japanese

**A's (B's C)**:

- 大阪の道の駅
  [Roadside stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roadside_station) in Osaka
- ニューヨークの自由の女神
  The Statue of Liberty in New York
- 円周率の3番目の数字
  the third digit of π

**Whatever** :

- 今日の東京の天気
  today's weather in Tokyo / weather in Tokyo today
- 本物の恐竜の写真
  pictures of real dinosaurs / real pictures of dinosaurs
- ピンク色の熊のぬいぐるみ
  pink stuffed bear / stuffed pink bear

**Ambiguous**:

- ハワイの宝の地図
  the map of Hawaiian Treasure / the treasure map in Hawaii
- 彼の親についての話
  his story about parents (in general) / story about his parents
- ピンク色の犬の尻尾
  the pink tail of a dog / the tail of a pink dog