# Takagi-san: Can it be ambiguous to say の (no) 2x?

Tags: particle-の, anime, possession

There's this anime original episode of Takagi-san, [namely S03E06](https://karakai-jouzu-no-takagi-san.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_6/Season_3). Since it's anime original I can't look up the manga to verify the exact dialogue, but... I think Nishikata says (see [here 1:08 - 1:19](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjZMEwoucvo&t=66s))

> boku tachi no ai no kiseki (ぼくたちの愛の奇跡)

1. Is that right?

---

Edit: Ah wait there's closed captions. Here you go:

> [image]

Looks like

> 僕たちの愛の軌跡

I have a feeling [軌跡](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%BB%8C%E8%B7%A1#Japanese) is wrong, but [僕](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%83%95#Pronoun) is right?

---

2. Is that ambiguous? If not, then why is it clear / how is it clarified?

I think it's like the double underscore in mathjax / maths stackexchange like 'x_t_1' can be either x_(t_1) or (x_t)_1. Here this sounds like it can be either of the ff

- 2.1. 'our love miracle' (as in like: our 'X', where 'X' is 'love miracle') or like 'a love miracle that is ours' for ぼくたちの **[愛の奇跡]**
- 2.2. 'miracle of our love' for **[ぼくたちの愛]** の奇跡

Actually, in this context, my initial guess is (2.2), but afterwards Takagi repeats '愛の奇跡' so I guess it's actually (2.1).

This sounds similar btw to [that tachi issue](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95550/can-you-call-a-group-of-people-by-a-subgroup-of-2-and-if-so-then-how) eg 'Ashanti-san と Bidatz-san たち' where it means either of the ff

- 2.3. Ashanti-san と [Bidatz-san たち] - Ashanti-san and the group of Bidatz-san
- 2.4. [Ashanti-san と Bidatz-san] たち - the group of the subgroup Ashanti-san and Bidatz-san

Or even just in English when you say, idk, '[red hammer](https://trickla.com/red-hammer-trick/) and screwdriver' where it's ambiguous if 'red' describes 'screwdriver' too.

3. Can it be ambiguous in another context? If so, then how could this be clarified? In general, can double の's be ambiguous, and how would they be clarified?

- 3.1. Say you're playing some RPG and then there are these power-ups or whatever, where 1 kind of power-up is called a 'love miracle' that can be obtained by 2 players working together. Then when 2 players work together to obtain such a power-up, 1 player may refer to their new power-up as (2.1)...not (2.2) right?
- 3.2. I notice Nishikata does pause between 'ぼくたち' and 'の', so idk maybe the pause is a way to clarify? Like how you'd pause when saying 'ittekimasu' unlike [Anya from Spy x Family](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJ7DcCOJDT0&t=89s) who says 行てきます instead of 行ってきます?

Comment: Do these answer your question? [Dealing with の ambiguities](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/83441/dealing-with-%e3%81%ae-ambiguities) / [General meaning of AとBのC?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55853/5010) It's 奇跡 (きせき【HLL】). 軌跡 is きせき【LHH】.

Comment: In this case, the meaning doesn't change largely whichever way you parse it, so I won't say it's ambiguous.